# Ghostclicks in mobile apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

There is a lot of material/posts on ghost clicks and I'm trying to understand it better. So the way I understand it, the reason for ghost clicks is the `click` event being dispatched ~300ms after the touch event. [jQuery Mobile suggests](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) to not use their `vclick` event whenever there is any chance of changing the content underneath the finger position.

*My first question* would be: Does that mean ghost clicks will only fire if the element targeted by `click` is different from the one originally touched? So, say, I write a database entry when a button is touched – nothing else. Is there a chance of ghost clicking or not?

If this is the case, wouldn't that mean that I can prevent ghost clicks altogether if I simply use *only* `tap` events and no `click` events whatsoever?

My last question would be if I can simply tell the browser to not use the 300ms delay when using PhoneGap (which would instantly solve the problem), but I'd just guess that I can't do that as it's probably hard-coded into the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event is delayed by 300 ms to detect things like double tap or fat finger mistakes.

Yes, wherever possible you should use the touch events instead.

Yes, there are many ways to enable fast clicks by doing a bit of JS. For instance:

1. https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons
2. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-jquery-mobile
3. http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/

You don't have to live with the 300ms delay.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am aware of those solutions. However, I tried them before and none of them worked reliably (f.ex. when navigating between pages). So are you saying that it is safe to use touch events if the content doesn't change (because the delayed `click` event won't trigger it a second time)?

Comment: Okay I just read on the developers.google.com site that the `preventDefault()` takes care of that (makes sense…). So I guess it is safe as long as the content doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

If everything on your page that can be clicked has the appropriate `vclick` jQuery event handlers installed, then one easy way of stopping ghost clicks is create a `touchend` event handler on the body and call `preventDefault` from it:

```
$(document.body).on('touchend', null, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that this will *disable regular clicks from touches*, so any conventional links or form inputs you have will stop working unless you add vclick handlers to them.