# Emulate CSS hover:before and hover:after behavior tooltips for touchscreens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very nice CSS-only hover tooltip solution like so:

[image: screenshot]

Works great on non-touchscreens but on touchscreens a click shows the tip and it never hides.  I am trying to get a toggling solution which keeps the work I have done and adds a touchscreen jQuery or CSS solution to show and hide the tooltips. I'd like to have the show/hide toggle on click but a solution with delay() would also do.

I have read

[Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery)

[Access the css ":after" selector with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

[How to modify programmatically with javascript the css ::before and ::after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997744/how-to-modify-programmatically-with-javascript-the-css-before-and-after)

Here is the current code

JS added today to try to resolve for touchscreens:

```
$('.tooltip').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('tooltipBefore tooltipAfter').delay( 800 ).removeClass('tooltipBefore tooltipAfter');
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Putts per round is the average number of putts per round played." >
    <span title="Info"><img src="/g/inputs/help.png"></span>
</a>
```

CSS - modified today to add .tooltipBefore .tooltipAfter which I also tried with :before and :after selectors added

```
    .tooltip{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }

.tooltip:hover:after, .tooltipAfter:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before, .tooltipBefore:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Revised JS per @maioman answer to below.  Console log i verifying that the correct element is being selected by `$(this)` but in Chrome inspector the class flashes but is never modified by addClass or removeClass.  Also tried toggleClass but class is not added.
**END EDIT 2**

```
console.log($(this).attr("Title"));
$(this).addClass('tooltipBefore').addClass('tooltipAfter').delay( 3000 ).removeClass('tooltipBefore').removeClass('tooltipAfter');
```

**EDIT 3**
OK, so edit #2 has issues with how I call the addClass and removeClass.  This version works in browser but and toggles class correctly but still does not work on phone:

```
$('.tooltip').bind( "click touchstart", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('tooltipBefore tooltipAfter');
});
```

**END EDIT 3**

Comment: so the option with delay is not working?

Answer (score 1):

try changing this

```
 $('.tooltip').click( function () {
```

to

```
 $('.tooltip').on('click touchstart', function () {
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`.  Did that function change to delegate() or something it seems like...

Comment: Ah- on() replaced bind() and delegate()

Comment: Using `$('.tooltip').bind( "click touchstart", function() {`  gets same result as before- tooltip shows but never hides.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219017/ghostclicks-in-mobile-apps

Comment: Thanks will look.  Added edit above.  addClass and toggleClass are failing to modify the element when veiwed in Chrome inspector on desktop